# vb.net Regexp Split comma separated String

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I have a `String`, which contains a list of mail addresses like so:

```
Dim address1 As String = """Merkel, Angela"" <angela@example.com>, ""Peter Altmeyer"" <peter@example.com>"
```

what I'm trying to archieve is to separate the `String` at the comma. I figure I need [`Regexp.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ze12yx1d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) therefore, but I don't have a clue, what exactly I have to do to get the output array of

```
"Merkel, Angela" <angela@example.com>
"Peter Altmeyer" <peter@example.com>
```

I'm especially confused by the double quotation mark `""` to escape the quotation mark. Is this also escaped like so in the regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it with the `String.Split` method, by including the ">" in the separator (">, "); however the ">" will be missing from the result and will have to re-add it.

With Regex you can do it as follows:

```
Dim parts() As String = Regex.Split(address1, "(?<=>),\s")
```

Here I am using the Regex pattern

```
(?<=prefix)find
```

which finds a position following a prefix. The result does not include the prefix. Therefore only `", "` is removed from the output and the ">" remains.

Comment: No, this would chunk up the first address like `"Merkel` and `Angela" <angela@example.com>`

Answer (score 1):

You can split on this RegEx: `(?<=>),\s*?(?="")`. It finds commas (with zero or more whitespaces after) preceded by a `<` and proceeded by a `""`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim address1 As String = """Merkel, Angela"" <angela@example.com>, ""Peter Altmeyer""     <peter@example.com>"
Dim parts() As String = Regex.Split(address1, "(?<=>),\s*?(?="")")
```